# For any pip install SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

Tags: python, pip

I am new to Ubuntu. Trying to setup python (for Ansible control system).
As part of this setup I need to install xmltodict and markupsafe. I think I'm missing some configuration setup part.

Env#

Windows 10 with VirtualBox, on which Ubuntu 18.x vbox.
pip --version (pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

```
$ pip install xmltodict
No matching distribution found for xmltodict
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for xmltodict
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699688/pip-install-xmltodict-not-working

Here's the same question. You can install with on ubuntu:

sudo apt-get install -y python-xmltodict